# Cannot find logs under ~/airflow/logs/scheduler folder

Tags: airflow

I'm running a dag on my local machine, and the dag definition is as follows:

```
with DAG(
    "usage_stat",
    description = "usage_stat_data_processing",
    schedule_interval = '48 16 * * *',
    start_date = datetime(2023, 1, 1),
    on_success_callback = dag_success_alert,
    catchup=False
) as dag:
```

I want the dag to call the `dag_success_alert` when it successfully executes. However, I wanna know what I can expect from the dag's `context` object, so I wrote the following function to print out dag's `context`:

```
def dag_success_alert(context):
    print(context)
    for key in context.keys():
        print("This is a new key: " + key)
        try:
            print(context[key].__dict__)
        except:
            continue
```

What I cannot figure out is where I can find the log file in which the outputs of `print` statements are stored.
I have done some research and they all point to `~/airflow/logs/scheduler` folder; however, this folder is empty.
I also tried changing the `logging_level` in `~/airflow/airflow.cfg` file from `INFO` to `DEBUG`, but that did not help, either.

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you verify value you've setup for your base_log_folder? If you've access to Airflow Web UI, you can check under Admin -> Configurations.

Default one is /opt/airflow/logs, and for scheduler /opt/airflow/logs/scheduler.

Comment: I realized the `/usr/local` is pointing at the containers' file system.